# Panel doesn't fully refresh when using a custom background in wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

Here's some sample code:

```
import wx

class MainPanel(wx.Panel):

p1 = None
p2 = None

def __init__(self, parent):

    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)

    self.frame = parent
    #self.SetBackgroundStyle(wx.BG_STYLE_CUSTOM)
    #self.bg = wx.Bitmap("2.jpg")

    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.OnMouseMove)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnMouseDown)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)

    self.SetCursor(wx.StockCursor(wx.CURSOR_CROSS))

def OnMouseMove(self, event):
    if event.Dragging() and event.LeftIsDown():
        self.p2 = event.GetPosition()
        self.Refresh()

def OnMouseDown(self, event):
    self.p1 = event.GetPosition()

def OnPaint(self, event):
    if self.p1 is None or self.p2 is None: return

    dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
    dc.SetPen(wx.Pen('red', 3, wx.LONG_DASH))
    dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush(wx.Color(0, 0, 0), wx.SOLID))
    dc.DrawRectangle(self.p1.x, self.p1.y, self.p2.x - self.p1.x, self.p2.y - self.p1.y)


class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
def __init__(self):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, size=(600,450))
    panel = MainPanel(self)        
    self.Center()

class Main(wx.App):
def __init__(self, redirect=False, filename=None):
    wx.App.__init__(self, redirect, filename)
    dlg = MainFrame()
    dlg.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
app = Main()
app.MainLoop()
```

The two offending lines are:

```
    #self.SetBackgroundStyle(wx.BG_STYLE_CUSTOM)
    #self.bg = wx.Bitmap("2.jpg")
```

If you run the code like that, you're able to draw a rectangle on the panel. If you start a new rectangle, the old one disappears, because the panel is refreshing.

However, if you uncomment those two lines, when you draw a rectangle, it stays there. You can have infinite number of rectangles. If I use dc.Clear(), the background disappears and reloading the background makes the application slow and it flickers.

How do I make the panel fully refresh while using a custom background?

By the way, the background image doesn't load with this code, but the behavior is the same.

**EDIT:** I found a workaround to the flickering caused by using dc.Clear() and reloading the background. Setting double buffering on the panel to true solves the flickering:

```
self.SetDoubleBuffered(True)
```

I will use that, but I'll leave the question open in case someone knows the answer to the initial problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the wx.BG_STYLE_CUSTOM background style it assumes that you will paint (or clear) the entire window in the EVT_PAINT event handler.  The easiest way to do that without flicker is to only push pixels to the screen one time per paint event.

Using SetDoubleBuffered does that at the system level, although that has been known to have side-effects in some cases.  Another easy way is to use a wx.BufferedPaintDC instead of wx.PaintDC.  It will create a bitmap that is the target of all the drawing operations and then  at the end the contents of the bitmap will be flushed to the screen.

Comment: Hi Robin, nice to see you answering questions here. Thanks for the explanation, at first I thought it was a bug, but your explanation makes sense. I ended up drawing the background on the erase event, based on a code suggested by you that I found on another site. That way I don't need to use wx.BG_STYLE_CUSTOM nor dc.Clear(). I still use SetDoubleBuffered, though.